# Import data using read.table with classLabel column type char and other columns are numeric in R

Tags: r

I have a data file that look like this :

```
 char   x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4 x5 y5 x6 y6 x7 y7 x8 y8 x9 y9   
  n 0.1875 0.140625 0.09375 0.515625 0 0.8828125 0.1796875 0.5078125 0.4609375 0.140625 0.640625  0.109375 0.515625 0.5390625 0.3828125 0.8828125 0.671875 0.9765625
  h 0 0 0.046875 0.3125 0.0625 0.671875 0.15625 0.765625 0.328125 0.4609375 0.4609375 0.3359375 0.625    0.4609375 0.6015625 0.7421875 0.53125 0.9921875
  y 0.0078125 0.0859375 0.140625 0.1875 0.2578125 0.375 0.4140625 0.421875 0.5078125 0.1484375 0.484375  0.1953125 0.28125 0.5234375 0.125 0.7734375 0 0.9765625
```

Now the first column char is the class label. I am trying to read this data into a table using

```
 fileContents <- read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE , sep =" ").
```

I know I am missing some argument of read.table but not sure which one to use in this situation.

The results that I am getting for the first and last row of this dataset are as follows :

```
head(fileContents, n = 1)

 char.x1       y1      x2       y2 x3        y3        x4        y4        x5       y5
 1 n\t0.1875 0.140625 0.09375 0.515625  0 0.8828125 0.1796875 0.5078125 0.4609375 0.140625

       x6       y6       x7        y7        x8        y8       x9        y9
 1 0.640625 0.109375 0.515625 0.5390625 0.3828125 0.8828125 0.671875 0.9765625

 tail(fileContents, n = 1)

       char.x1    y1        x2        y2      x3        y3      x4 y4       x5        y5
  5000 e\t0.2265625 0.125 0.4921875 0.2890625 0.84375 0.2109375 0.84375  0 0.390625 0.0234375

           x6       y6 x7        y7        x8       y8        x9        y9
  5000 0.15625 0.203125  0 0.5859375 0.1328125 0.953125 0.5234375 0.9921875
```

However I need the results in this format:

```
  char x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4

    n 0.1875 0.140625 0.09375 0.515625 0 0.8828125 0.1796875 0.5078125

    x5 y5 x6 y6 x7 y7 x8 y8

    0.4609375 0.140625 0.640625 0.109375 0.515625 0.5390625 0.3828125 0.8828125

    x9 y9

    0.671875 0.9765625
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: I tried with `dat <- read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE , sep =""); dim(dat)#[1]  3 19`

Comment: Your question would be more clear from the perspective of the R tag, if it was titled Import...

Comment: Aah! the only difference was my argument sep = " " instead of sep ="". Does that really make a difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a "column" of tabs (\t) after the char field. Use the line below. Note sep is the empty string, which considers any whitespace to be a delimiter.  With `sep = " "` you were explicitly stating that the space is the separator.

```
fileContents <- read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE , sep = "")
```

Comment: Me too actually. I most often use comma separated text.